# mx.chart.AxisRenderer labelRotation not working

Tags: apache-flex, components

I'm attempting to rotate the category labels on my flex chart, but the labelRotation property seems to not work. Based on examples and the livedocs, I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```
<mx:BarChart id="barchartX" left="40" right="40" bottom="40" paddingBottom="40"
         dataProvider="{chartDataObj.series}" showDataTips="false"
         itemClick="editItem_clickHandler(event)" includeIn="BAR" visible="true">
    <mx:verticalAxis>
         <mx:CategoryAxis id="vaxis" categoryField="title" 
                          title="click here to rename this axis" /> 
    </mx:verticalAxis>

    <mx:verticalAxisRenderers>
         <mx:AxisRenderer axis="{vaxis}" labelRotation="45"
                          click="axis_clickHandler(event)"/>
    </mx:verticalAxisRenderers>

    <mx:horizontalAxis>
        <mx:LinearAxis id="haxis" title="click here to rename this axis" />
    </mx:horizontalAxis>

    <mx:horizontalAxisRenderers>
        <mx:AxisRenderer axis="{haxis}" labelRotation="0"       
                             click="axis_clickHandler(event)"/>
    </mx:horizontalAxisRenderers>

    <mx:series>
        <mx:BarSeries labelPosition="none" yField="title" xField="value" 
                          fills="{chartDataObj.colors}"/>
    </mx:series>
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that this is a mobile project using Flash Builder 4.5.1. The fact that it's a mobile project seems to be the cause of this not working properly. As noted in the livedocs:
"labelRotation
Type: Number CSS Inheritance: no
Specifies the label rotation. If the labels are rendered with device fonts, the labels are always drawn horizontally. If this style is any negative value, the AxisRenderer determines an optimal angle to render the labels in the smallest area without overlapping."

So, since the labels are using device fonts, they're always horizontal.

Comment: ... However, when I tried to style the chart to use a CSS @font-face embedded font, I've received errors.

Answer (score 1):

I am including my answer to a similar question, https://stackoverflow.com/a/9129992/892191

---

The key to making the labelRotation work is embedding of fonts.
There is a good article on Flex 4.6 [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf65816-7fe5.html)

A simple code example would be to add a style to the mxml file,

```
<fx:Style>
        @namespace mx "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx";

        @font-face{
            src: local("Arial");
            fontFamily: Arial;
            embedAsCFF: false;
        }

        mx|ColumnChart {
            fontFamily: Arial;
            fontSize: 10;
        }
</fx:Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after searching through the actual code of the AxisRenderer I came up with this:

```
<fx:Script>
     [Embed(source='../assets/verdana.ttf', 
            fontName='verdanaFontMX', 
            mimeType='application/x-font',
            embedAsCFF='false')] 
     private var font2:Class;
</fx:Script>    

<mx:verticalAxisRenderers>
            <mx:AxisRenderer axis="{vaxis}" labelRotation="90"
                                 labelClass="mx.controls.Label" 
                                 fontFamily="verdanaFontMX" canStagger="false"
                                 click="axis_clickHandler(event)"/>
    </mx:verticalAxisRenderers>
```

When using a CategoryAxis for an MX chart in a mobile project, the category labels are rendered as Spark Labels, but the rest of the axis labels are rendered as MX Labels. The label rotation works, but a warning is thrown and the category is rendered using the device font instead. To fix this, use the MX Label class instead (labelClass="mx.controls.Label"). I know it doesn't render quickly as the Spark label, but it will render in the font you want.

Next, if you have a category label that's very long, somehow there is division by zero and the whole thing crashes. To avoid this, set canStagger="false" or canDropLabels="true". This avoids whatever measurement errors were happening. However, if the fontSize is set, and the label ends up being too large, the automatic sizing crashes again. So, I guess the easiest solution would be to keep the category labels short.

There is also the possibility of truncating the text as found here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS02f7d8d4857b1677355f601a126b41ed60e-8000.html
or, using a custom labelRenderer, but this can get very involved and can have diminishing returns on the amount of work versus the benefit to the look.