# AxisRenderer's labelRotation property doesn't do anything

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, charts

Despite setting the labelRotation property to 90 in this column chart, the axis labels are horizontal. Is there something additional I need to do?

```
    <mx:ColumnChart id="myChart" height="100%" width="100%"
                    dataProvider="{myData}"
                    showDataTips="true">
        <mx:horizontalAxis>
            <mx:CategoryAxis id="h1" categoryField="code"/>
        </mx:horizontalAxis>            
        <mx:horizontalAxisRenderers>
            <mx:AxisRenderer axis="{h1}" labelRotation="90" />
        </mx:horizontalAxisRenderers>           
        <mx:series>
            <mx:ColumnSet type="stacked"
                          allowNegativeForStacked="true">
                <mx:series>
                    <mx:ColumnSeries xField="code"
                                     yField="A"
                                     displayName="A"/>
                    <mx:ColumnSeries xField="code"
                                     yField="B"
                                     displayName="B"/>
                    <mx:ColumnSeries xField="code"
                                     yField="C"
                                     displayName="C"/>
                    <mx:ColumnSeries xField="code"
                                     yField="D"
                                     displayName="D"/>
                    <mx:ColumnSeries xField="code"
                                     yField="F"
                                     displayName="F"/>
                </mx:series>
            </mx:ColumnSet>
        </mx:series>
    </mx:ColumnChart>
```

EDIT: I tried embedding the font, as suggested by Amy and fotomut, but it didn't do anything:

```
<mx:Style>
 @font-face 
 {
    src:url("../assets/fonts/FRABK.ttf");
fontFamily: myFontFamily; 
embedAsCFF: false; 
 }

ColumnChart 
 { 
        fontFamily: myFontFamily; 
        fontSize: 10; 
     } 

</mx:Style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to making the labelRotation work is embedding of fonts.
There is a good article on Flex 4.6 [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf65816-7fe5.html)

A simple code example would be to add a style to the mxml file,

```
<fx:Style>
        @namespace mx "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx";

        @font-face{
            src: local("Arial");
            fontFamily: Arial;
            embedAsCFF: false;
        }

        mx|ColumnChart {
            fontFamily: Arial;
            fontSize: 10;
        }
</fx:Style>
```

---

EDIT:
I confirmed that this works for me using Flex 3.5, by simply changing `fx:Style` to `mx:Style`

```
<mx:Style>
    @namespace mx "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx";

    @font-face{
        src: local("Arial");
        fontFamily: Arial;
        embedAsCFF: false;
    }

    mx|ColumnChart {
        fontFamily: Arial;
        fontSize: 10;
    }
</mx:Style>
```

Perhaps you should try embedding Arial like this first to see if that works?

Comment: I am using Flex 4.1, which is why my Style namespace is FX.
I notice you have <mx:style>, are you on Flex 3.5? If so, maybe 3.5 doesn't use the embedded font for rotation in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

Embed the font used on that label. If for some reason you can't embed the font, sometimes setting the blendMode to "layer" will work.

Comment: Try embedding the bold variant--they might have made those labels bold by default.